# Error : '[UILabel]' doesn't have a member named 'viewWithTag' ?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

```
var theLabel : UILabel? = self.lblCollection.viewWithTag(textField.tag) as? UILabel
```

`viewWithTag` method that was available in Objective-C, has now been discarded? If yes what is the replacement to access Label  collection using tag ?

Comment: Is `self.lblCollection` a view or a collection of IBOutlet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to work on array of UILabel

Try this

```
var theLabel : UILabel? = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag) as? UILabel;
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewWithTag:` is still there. The issue is you are calling that on an `IBOutletCollection` (Means an array of `UILabel`).

Either you should do it like:

```
var theLabel : UILabel? = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag) as? UILabel;
```

or

```
for label in self.lblCollection
{
    if label.tag == textField.tag
    {
        // Do the stuff here            
    }
}
```